# top header span the whole width of site

Tags: html, css

Just building a website and I want to do something I haven't come across yet. When the top of the site has no margin but the main content does have, same as the top of [this site](http://surreypaintingdecoratingservices.co.uk/).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

currently I have given it:

```
<div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
```

Just a bit stuck.

Comment: #header { width=100%; }
#body { width=90%; } ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... do you mean the background spanning the whole width on the header and fixed width on the main content?

Comment: I want to extend by nav bar all the way out - here it is live: http://thisdigicore.com/bds/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body and/or html element will have margin and/or padding by default (the exact values depend on the browser).

If you remove them, then any div (if you don't apply CSS that restricts the width) that is a child of the body will then fill the width of the window.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can then set a margin on the main content.

```
#main_content {
    margin: 5px 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this is what you need to do in css:

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

That's all.